# JavaFX without Gui

Tags: java, javafx, mp3

I would like to use JavaFX media player to play mp3 without any GUI.

I saw a lot of examples online, but all of them create JFX Frames.

When I run following code:

```
protected static void playSong(){
    String bip = "file:///c:/a/a.mp3"; 
    Media hit = new Media(bip);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
    mediaPlayer.play();
    System.out.print(true);
}
```

I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        playSong();
    }
}
```

Comment: The program do not terminate after the media is played completely.